# trouble with zlib and rvm on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-lion

I've been trying to get Rails going on Lion, and have been having quite a bit of trouble.  I know there are lots of posts here about this, and I've read a lot of them.  I haven't been able to find my specific issue though.  I was able to use rvm to install Ruby 1.9.2.  Then the trouble starts:

```
$ gem install rails --version 3.0.9
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

So I try:

```
$ rvm pkg install zlib
Fetching zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz to /Users/neal/.rvm/archives
Extracting zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz to /Users/neal/.rvm/src
Configuring zlib in /Users/neal/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5.
Compiling zlib in /Users/neal/.rvm/src/zlib-1.2.5.
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make ', please read /Users/neal/.rvm/log/zlib/make.log
Installing zlib to /Users/neal/.rvm/usr
```

The log file has the following at the end:

```
ld: in libz.a(!<arch>
#1/20), archive member '!<arch>
#1/20' with length 100644 is not mach-o or llvm bitcode for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

Anyway, I'm willing to be there's a simple solution to this, but I don't really know what I'm doing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: As you are back, could you please accept one of these answers or at least indicate why they are not sufficient? Do followup on your questions, iamtheneal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I finally ran

rvm implode

then reinstalled with this official walk through.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

gems and RVM work fine for me now. Implode will completely remove your install of RVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ARCHFLAGS and CC variables first and then try and install. That should do the trick:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
export CC=gcc-4.2
rvm pkg install zlib
```